# How to filter data with condition dependent on dataframe names

Tags: r, list, dplyr, lapply

I have a list of tables produced by lapply and give them names

```r
FIF.result <- lapply (c("A5", "A6"), FIF.calc)
```

and give them names

```r
names(FIF.result) <- c("A5", "A6")
```

I want to apply a filter with a condition dependent on dataframe names.

Pseudocode:

```
FIF.result <- lapply (FIF.result, function (x) {
  if (names (x) == "A5") {
    x <- x %>% filter (wskaznik > 20)
  } else {
    x <- x %>% filter (wskaznik > 25)
  }
})
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If we cant reproduce `FIF.calc` then it is much more difficult to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map`, i.e. `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`), a multivariate version of `lapply()`.

```r
Map(function(df, nms) {
  if (nms == "A5") {
    df %>% filter(wskaznik > 20)
  } else {
    df %>% filter(wskaznik > 25)
  }
}, FIF.result, names(FIF.result))
```

Its `purrr` equivalent is `imap()`:

```r
library(purrr)

imap(FIF.result, ~ {
  if (.y == "A5") {
    .x %>% filter(wskaznik > 20)
  } else {
    .x %>% filter(wskaznik > 25)
  }
})
```

where `.x` represents each `data.frame` in the list and `.y` is the list name.

---

###### Example Data

```r
FIF.result <- list(A5 = data.frame(wskaznik = 1:30),
                   A6 = data.frame(wskaznik = 1:30))
```

###### Output

```
$A5
   wskaznik
1        21
2        22
3        23
4        24
5        25
6        26
7        27
8        28
9        29
10       30

$A6
  wskaznik
1       26
2       27
3       28
4       29
5       30
```